# What makes the hepatic portal vein unique?

Tags: anatomy, human-physiology, veins

What makes the hepatic portal vein unique?, is it because it begins and ends with capillaries or because it carries digested food.

Comment: **Homework questions** and **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on Biology **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. For more information see our [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework).